# Can I know if another user is logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have looked at the `AspNetUsers`-table, and cannot find any fields indicating whether the user is currently logged in or not.

My use case is an online meeting app with live chat and webcam streaming, so it would be good to know if the other meeting participants are online or not when you chat with them.

Does Identity have such functionality, or do I have to write it myself?

All my google-ing has only given me information about the currently logged in user. That's me, and I already KNOW that I am logged in...

Comment: Since the web is disconnected, "logged in" is a nebulous concept. The user can close the browser at any time - are they logged in or logged out?

Comment: @NetMage That's why, in my attempt of a solution, I am using the term "online probability".

Comment: Yes, really you are talking about "recent users of web page".

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I have put together this solution. I don't know if it would be good enough in a production environment:

On the `AspNetUser`, I added this property:

```
public DateTime? LastActive { get; set; }
```

I already have a ViewBag-filter, where I'm getting some info about the user, like number of unread messages and some design preferences, so I added an update on the user there:

```
public class ViewBagFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public ViewBagFilter(ApplicationDbContext _dbContext)
    {
        db = _dbContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Controller is BaseController controller)
        {
            if (Guid.TryParse(controller.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier), out Guid loggedInUserId))
            {
                // Note: It's important that any db-writing is done here, 
                // in OnActionExecuting(), and not in OnActionExecuted().
                // Otherwise, it will mess with the entity tracking and result
                // in "mysterious" changes to the database.
                ApplicationUser user = db.Users
                    .Where(u => u.Id == loggedInUserId).FirstOrDefault();
                user.LastActive = DateTime.Now;
                db.Update(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Controller is BaseController controller)
        {
            if (Guid.TryParse(controller.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier), out Guid loggedInUserId))
            {
                // Read info from db and set global ViewBags as needed

                // Example:
                ApplicationUser user = db.Users
                    .Where(u => u.Id == loggedInUserId).FirstOrDefault();
                int unread = db.MessageRecipients.Where(m =>
                    m.RecipientUserId == loggedInUserId &&
                    !m.IsRead).Count();
                controller.ViewBag.UnreadMessages = unread;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, in the `AspNetUserViewModel`, I added two strings, one for online status color (bootstrap alert-colors), and one for text:

```
private static DateTime Now => DateTime.Now;

public string OnlineProbabilityStatusColor => LastActive.HasValue
    ? (Now - LastActive.Value).TotalMinutes < 5
        ? "success" // High prob. <5 minutes since last activity
        : (Now - LastActive.Value).TotalMinutes < 10
            ? "warning" // Medium-low prob. 5-10 minutes since last activity.
            : (Now - LastActive.Value).TotalMinutes < 30
                ? "danger" // Low prob. 10-30 minutes.
                : "dark" // Very low prob. 30 minutes or more.
    : "dark"; // Not logged in.

public string OnlineProbabilityStatusText => LastActive.HasValue
    ? (Now - LastActive.Value).TotalMinutes < 5
        ? "Active less than 5 minutes ago"
        : (Now - LastActive.Value).TotalMinutes < 10
            ? "Active 5-10 minutes ago"
            : (Now - LastActive.Value).TotalMinutes < 30
                ? "Active 10-30 minutes ago"
                : "Active 30 minutes or longer ago"
    : "Not logged in";
```

Now I can indicate any user's online status like this:

```
<span class="fas fa-circle fa-fw text-@user.OnlineProbabilityStatusColor"
    title="@user.OnlineProbabilityStatusText"></span>
```